# list.reverse() is not giving the correct output

Tags: python, list, reverse

Question:
Write a function that accepts two positive integers a and b (a is smaller than b)and returns a list that contains all the odd numbers between a and b (including a and including b if applicable) in descending order.

Program:

```
def odd(a,b):
    c=[]
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        if i%2==1:
            c.append(i)
            c.sort()
            c.reverse()
        return c
```

Clarification:
I get the correct output only when I use **c.sort** and then reverse it. But `c.reverse` is supposed to give the correct output, right? When I "don't sort" and reverse the list, the output list comes in an improper order although the elements entered the list in a sorted order. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: how many times should it theoretically be necessary to call `reverse`? How many times are you actually calling it?

Comment: you can use `c.sort(reverse=True)` BTW. And do it in the end, not within the loop as it's inefficient. plus your items are already sorted so reverse would be enough

Comment: Your posted code puts a single number in the list and returns that one-element list.  Please post the code that actually produces your problem.

Comment: Oh my bad!  Thanks @Kevin and Jean

Answer (score 1):

others pointed out your mistakes. I'd like to provide a more performant solution:

```
def odd(a,b):
    return list(range(b if b%2 else b-1,a-1,-2))

print(odd(1,10))
print(odd(1,11))
```

result:

```
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
[11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

it uses `range` with a 2 step in reverse, and makes sure that it starts with an odd number.

Comment: That's great! Thanks @Jean-François Fabre

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` can be called after the loop instead of each iteration of the loop.  The return statement should also be outside of the loop.

```
def odd(a,b):
    c=[]
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        if i%2==1:
            c.append(i)
    c.reverse()
    return c

print(odd(1,10))

# Returns   [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks @TruBlu I got it